# Max parallel tasks in Console App, and how to handle "Error while copying content to stream" when calling API

Tags: c#, api, parallel-processing, task

I'm working on an integration that handles several large datasets (around 3M records or so, growing daily) which are pulling from a vendor OData API in chunks. When I run it/debug locally, the integration will run to completion without errors. However, as soon as I put it out on our PROD server, it will **sometimes** fail with "Error while copying content to stream" on a given chunk of data. I'm having trouble figuring out the reason, and could use some help.

Each request is wrapped in a using statement and should be disposing of itself cleanly. Usually, it does. Again, this all works perfectly on my local machine, but the server has a bit of trouble after it's into pulling millions of records. I have added extra logging at virtually every step to catch the specific error, but it's still not clear how to handle (or avoid) this error. It isn't consistent at all... totally intermittent and inconsistent.

The code where the error throws:

```
using (WebRequestHandler webRequestHandler = new WebRequestHandler())
{
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(webRequestHandler))
    {
        httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);

        ConfigureJsonClient(httpClient, syncConfig.ApiEndpoint, syncConfig.ApiAuthKey);

        apiCommand = "http://foo/with/filtering";

        responseMessage = Task.Run(async () => await httpClient.GetAsync(apiCommand)
            .ConfigureAwait(true)).Result;
    }
}
```

The error:

```
API Error Occurred - RETRYING... Foo: 2 | API CALL: https://foo... | EXCEPTION: One or more errors occurred. | INNER EXCEPTION: Error while copying content to a stream. | STACKTRACE:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
       at FooNamespace.Processor.GetDataFromApi(SyncConfig syncConfig, String collection, List`1 nonDatedCollectionList, Int32 skipIndex, Int32 retryCount, Int32 taskId)
```

I am also trying to run as many parallel tasks as I can to pull these large datasets in pre-defined chunks (data pages) using skip/take. No matter what I do, even locally, the max number of Tasks I can spin up in parallel is 40. Is there a reason for this limitation?

Is it possible the parallel tasks are conflicting with each other somehow when hitting the API? These should appear as completely separate, isolated calls...

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's almost impossible to tell what the problem might be from a description alone, can you share the portion of the code that calls the API and throws the error?

Comment: Sure - just added the code where the error occurs to the OP. Thanks again for any help.

Comment: One problem that I see right off the bat is the HttpClient initialization, that's NOT how you should be doing it, HttpClient is supposed to be initialized once per application.

Comment: "HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors. Below is an example using HttpClient correctly." from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Got it. I'll refactor the HttpClient so it's only initialized once.

Comment: I'm not sure if that what's causing the error, but it might be.

Comment: What is the intention of the `Task.Run` and the `ConfigureAwait(true)`? AFAIK console applications have no `SynchronizationContext`, so wrapping a `Task` into a `Task.Run` shouldn't offer any benefit, and only adds a (minuscule) overhead. Regarding `ConfigureAwait(true)`, this is the default, so including it just adds visual clutter to your code. Also, what are you doing with the `responseMessage` after disposing the `httpClient`?

Comment: I see what you meant on the Task.Run/ConfigureAwait. Refactored that out and used the standard GetAsync().Result. Tunnel vision I think.

I then parse ResponseMessage from each call, grab the JSON payload and feed it to a database sproc where it shreds the JSON for a DW process (out of scope for this). The HttpClient is disposed after all data has been downloaded and processed.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar exception `Error while copying content to a stream`. On the inner exception I've got `System.IO.IOException: The decryption operation failed`. I found that the server is sending the content compressed without the header `content-encoding: gzip`. Change de default value of the `AutomaticDecompression` property on `HttpClientHandler` solve the problem.

```
HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
httpClientHandler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All;
using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
```

Comment: HttpClient is meant to be reused. `using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))` is a bug. The OP's code contains a lot of bugs and attempts to cover them up. The HttpClient instance should be stored eg in a field and reused. The rest of the code can be replaced with `var responseMessage= await  _client.GetAsync(url);`

Comment: Besides, the error doesn't complain about encryption. Modifying the compression settings won't fix the actual problem. If this code, perhaps due to other bugs, ends up trying to read from the response when the HttpClient gets disposed, the same exception will be thrown

Comment: Yes this code can't be used as production code, in my case we use the [typed HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#typed-clients). But for debug proposes I've created a console app with a direct call like that. In my tests, the decryption exception is in the inner exception of HttpRequestException.